# How to make a union type of a record's keys type in Typescipt?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a type that converts a record to a union of all the types of it's keys.

###### Example:

Given the following type :

```js
type Foo = {
    key1: { bar: '1' };
    key2: { bar: '2' };
    key3: { bar: '3' };
}
```

I would like to create a type `KeysTypeUnion<T>` that validates :

```
KeysTypeUnion<Foo> == { bar: '1' } | { bar: '2' } | { bar: '3' }
```

I was only able to write it by hand like so:

```
FooKeysTypeUnion = typeof Foo.key1 | typeof Foo.key2 | typeof Foo.key3
```

But it would be helpful to make a type alias to save time.

###### Tests:

```
KeysTypeUnion<{ key1: '1'; key2: '2'; key3: '3' }> == '1' | '2' | '3'
```

```
KeysTypeUnion<Record<string, A | B | C>> == A | B | C
```

Comment: `type KeysTypeUnion<T> = T[keyof T]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create that in at least two different ways, one being a bit more general than the other.

The simple way is this:

```js
type KeysTypeUnion<Foo> = Foo[keyof Foo];
```

A more complicated way that is more general is this

```js
type KeysTypeUnion<Foo> = Foo extends {[k: string | number | symbol]: infer V} ? V : never;
```

refer to [this post](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-infer-typescript/) to understand the `infer` keyword

I think the name you choose is a bit confusing though, as it is the type of the values and not the keys. I mean, if we had an object of type `Foo`, let's call it `foo`, and ran `Object.values(foo)`, then it's the type of that that your `KeysTypeUnion` returns. I think `ValueOf<Foo>` would probably  be a better name and mirror the `keyof` operator and `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`. Though, probably the idiomatic name is `Foo[keyof Foo]`. It's pretty short and should be readable :)

Comment: Yes you're right, i think i missused the word "key" instead of using "attribute".

Answer (score 0):

```
type Foo = {
  key1: { bar: '1' };
  key2: { bar: '2' };
  key3: { bar: '3' };
}

type KeysTypeUnion<T> = T[keyof T]

type T0 = KeysTypeUnion<{ key1: '1'; key2: '2'; key3: '3' }> // "1" | "2" | "3"
type A = string
type B = boolean
type C = number
type T1 = KeysTypeUnion<Record<string, A | B | C>> // string | number | boolean
type T2 = KeysTypeUnion<Foo> // { bar: '1' } | { bar: '2' } | { bar: '3' }
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBrCICMAXGlAEYCGATsQOT41QC+A3JjngEzGplW0cMWbXCADM3XtSg1Rg1o3TpQkKAGk8AZwAq4CAFUAdgEs4BgDxaAfMihaA2iLgAzWwF1Fy6FoAMN9SG1dQxNzHhEiaXpmdhAuaQFokXFpWSZLJV0oAEEbDWBKIwMAcwyVACEbUgQAGwhyA1LoAGEbAwBXAFtSCEpG23w-TR1IYNMzACUIAGM4SgATMzyC4oAabKgAHygKrabLSyA)